# Cannot attach existing method to UIButton

Tags: swift

I'm attempting to make a mock-up application, but I cannot seem to get the UIButton to hook up to the action that should be executed when I click it.
I'm not sure why it cannot find the method, the names are the same and adding in a `(_:)` to the `#selector` does nothing.

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    var loginButton: UIButton?

    @objc func onLoginButtonPress(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("Login Button Press")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        setup()
    }

    func setup() -> Void {

        initLoginButton()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .green
    }

    func initLoginButton() -> Void {
        let loginButtonBounds = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 250, height: 250)
        loginButton = UIButton(frame: loginButtonBounds)
        loginButton!.backgroundColor = .red
        loginButton!.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)
        loginButton!.addTarget(self, action: #selector("onLoginButtonPress"), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(loginButton!)
    }
```

Comment: try  #selector(self. onLoginButtonPress(sender:))

Comment: Huh, that worked. Any ideas why? Everyplace I looked on google and SO had it in quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
loginButton!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onLoginButtonPress(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

edit this line code, this should work for you. Its better to not use **force-unwrapping** so avoid using it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the parenthesis from "onLoginButtonPress"? I don't think they are needed.

```
loginButton!.addTarget(self, action: #selector("onLoginButtonPress"), for: .touchUpInside)
```